# Failing to get Substring from Path in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

There are these two given paths

```
$x = 'C:\temp\folder1\data' 
$t = 'C:\temp\'
```

Desired is to get '\folder1\data' to a new variable

I tried

```
Select-String  -Path $x -Pattern $t
```

which ended in

```
Select-String: The string C:\temp\ is not a valid regular expression: Invalid pattern 'C:\temp\' at offset 8. Illegal \\ at end of pattern.
```

Also I tried to replace the backslash with a pipe symbol which ended in

```
Select-String: Cannot find path 'C:\|temp|folder1|data' because it does not exist.
```

This

```
$x -replace $t,""
```

does bring back

```
||folder1|data
```

Which is close.
How would I correctly extract a search string from a path string ins PS ?

Comment: What is your goal here? What should the output be? From the looks of it, you are looking for a pattern match of *C:\Temp* in your `$x` path\variable. What are you trying to accomplish? The error is basically telling you, that you need to escape the slash most commonly using another slash \\ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the string before you can use it as a regex pattern:

```
PS ~> $x -replace [regex]::Escape($t)
folder1\data
```

Trim `$t` before escaping if you don't want to remove the trailing slash:

```
PS ~> $x -replace [regex]::Escape($t.TrimEnd('\'))
\folder1\data
```

To ensure the replacement only occurs at the start of the string, add a caret `^`, which in regex is a metacharacter designating the "start of string":

```
$x -replace "^$([regex]::Escape($t.TrimEnd('\')))"
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. I hoped I could avoid regex ;-)

Comment: @user3732793 You can (`if($x.StartsWith($t)){$x.Substring($t.Length)}`), you just mentioned all the regex-ways that didn't work for you :)

Comment: did work thanks for the additional example